# Two conditions checking on listview group items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have list view (with one column). I have divided this list view into two groups like in the figure below.

My problem is: how can I find selection event like this: If I click on odd group item ("one") and then if I click on even group item ("two"), I want to do something.

How can I check these two conditions in a single `if` statement? These two conditions are the ones that need to be done in a single if statement. Is it possible to use a single condition?

[image]

I am using C# and WinForms apps. Would anyone please help on this?

**EDIT :**

```
  Category names
     name 1
     name 2
     name 3

   prices
    >100
    >200
    300+
```

If I click on category name and then I click on the price range, I want to do something. Is it possible to do both in single condition checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the SelectedIndexChanged event like so:

```
void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>();
    var passed = (selectedItems.Select(l => l.Group.Name).Distinct().Count() == 2 && selectedItems.Count() == 2);
    if (passed)
    {
         //Do something...
    }
}
```

---

**Edit (based on comments)**

To retrieve each selected item use the following:

**Note:** For the below code to work you would need to set the Name property of each of your ListViewGroup's to "Category" and "Prices" respectively.

```
void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>();
    var passed = (selectedItems.Select(l => l.Group.Name).Distinct().Count() == 2 && selectedItems.Count() == 2);
    if (passed)
    {
        var categoryItem = selectedItems.Where(l => l.Group.Name.ToLower() == "category").Single();
        var priceItem = selectedItems.Where(l => l.Group.Name.ToLower() == "prices").Single();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it applicable to that list i have edited my question would you pls take a look at the question... If i select the category name and then i select the price range i want to do something..... would you pls help...